# Get Data from a List of a dictonary

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I got some data from a file:

```
[
     {
       "Boodie#1932": [
         {
           "cash": 20,
           "lastHourly": "21$28"
         }
       ]
     }
      "MrDacom#9952": [
        {
          "cash": 20,
          "lastHourly": "21$28"
        }
      ]
    ]
```

Now I want to read out the cash from "MrDacom#9952". How can I do this? 
Things like this:

```
data['MrDacom#9952']['cash']
```

don't work.

Comment: _don't work._ What happens instead? Any idea why that might not work?

Comment: This was just an example to show that I cant access the data like a normal dictonary :)

Comment: Are you actually able to read that into a variable? The outer dict seems to end before "MrDacom#9952", so I would expect an exception.

Comment: @mrdacom None of that really addresses what I wrote in my comment? Also, the format of the data you shared is not valid Python, please clarify what exactly it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code
`data['MrDacom#9952']['cash']` 
does not work because `data` is a list.

The right way to access it can be:

`data[0]['MrDacom#9952'][0]['cash']`

Comment: didn't worked. But when I print out data[0]['MrDacom#9952'] I get back another list: [{'cash': 20, 'lastHourly': '21$28'}]

Comment: I didn't notice that your dictionaries hold lists as well. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try: `data[0]['MrDacom#9952'][0]['cash']`

Answer (score 0):

Following will work

```
data['MrDacom#9952'][0]['cash']
```